# Thoughts in ghusl

Tags: taharah, ghusl

If you have dirty thoughts in ghusl but don’t get accompanied by feelings of arousal or such, do you have to start ghusl all over again or just continue?

Comment: Why should you restart ghusl?

Answer (score 1):

Ghusl is required when you are accompanied and perform intercourse or when you have excretion. Just thoughts don't nullify your previously performed ghusl or ongoing ghusl